# Showing the natural number same cardinality as as even?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having problem with the onto part of this problem.

$\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}$

My function or pattern is

$x \rightarrow f(x)=2x$

Which take my natural to even.

**One to One**

$f(x)=f(y)$

$2x=2y$

$x=y$

**Onto**

Let

$n\in E$

Not I have to make $x$ equal something when plug into $f(x)$ that will give n ,for all n in even.

And I cannot say let $x=\frac{1}{2}n$

Because the domain is a natural one.

Comment: You can actually say $x=n/2$. Bcoz n is an even number, so it is divisible by 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can't talk about square roots of integers either, but $3$ is *still* the square root of $9$.

The fact that $\frac n2$ is not defined in the general case is irrelevant here. What's important is that $\frac n2$ is well defined for all the numbers in $\Bbb E$.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. Is it than since n is even divide by two we will get another even, and not a fraction. So I do not have have to worry about rationals in the domain.

Comment: We *can* talk about square roots of integers, no? It's just not always an integer, if that's what you mean, so we can only talk about square root of certain integers?

Comment: Ok I think I understand this set theory has a lot of intricacies.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: The first comment you made has a small flaw. Dividing a even by 2 doesn't necessarily give you an even number but an integer for sure. For example, 6 divides 2 is 3.

Comment: alright yes you are right

Comment: @naslundx: In the context of the integers, we can't talk about arbitrary square roots. Because it demands a larger context.

Comment: @Fernando: "This set theory" is no different than any part of mathematics. One has to be careful in applying the definitions and notice what one can and cannot do.

Comment: @naslundx ,Asaf Karagila- We can talk of arbitrary square root of integers provided we know the ambient space we are working in. If we are just working with integers, then we cannot talk of square roots, but if we are ready to work with irrational, then yes we can talk of square root of integers.

Comment: @Susobhan: Yes, "ambient space we are working in" is exactly what I meant by "context".

Answer (score 2):

An element of E is of the form $2m$ where $m \in \mathbb Z$. So the $x$ you are finding will be $m$